# XAML DataGrid binding to runtime-empty DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

Is it possible to bind `DataGrid` to a `DataTable` which is set to `new DataTable()` at runtime but filled with columns and data afterwards? This is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgClients" ItemsSource="{Binding clientsTable}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</ViProDataGrid>
```

and this is my c# code:

```
public DataTable clientsTable = new DataTable(); (global variable)

** the following code is executing after app initialization
DataTable dtTemp = SearchClients(param1);

clientsTable.Columns.Add("Id", dtTemp.Columns["oldIdColumn"].DataType);
clientsTable.Columns.Add("Name", dtTemp.Columns["oldNameColumn"].DataType);

for (int i = 0; i < dtTemp.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   var tmpRow = clientsTable.NewRow();
   tmpRow["Id"] = dtTemp.Rows[i]["oldIdColumn"];
   tmpRow["Name"] = dtTemp.Rows[i]["oldNameColumn"];
   clientsTable.Rows.Add(tmpRow);
}
```

If I set ItemsSource in my code after my `DataTable` is being filled and set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, `DataGrid` is showing good data, but that is not the way I want it done. The thing is, Columns must be set in XAML.
I tried with `DataGrid.Items.Refresh()` and setting `DataContext` to my `DataTable`.

Comment: How'd you create a global variable in C#? Anyhow, try giving `clientsTable` looks like a regular public instance field to me, so you can probably make it bindable just by turning it into a property: `public DataTable clientsTable { get; } = new DataTable();` If you're not in C#6, you'll have to initialize it differently; let me know. If it's not defined in your viewmodel, it needs to be. Setting `DataContext` to your `DataTable` is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: It did not help, still no data in `DataGrid`